# Using Protobuf-net .proto schema in Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, protobuf-net

I have an existing Web API project, which after running some tests, I want to start implementing protobuf.  Using the `Serializer.GetProto<>()` method, I got the following data (showing just the beginning):

```
syntax = "proto2";
package MyProject.Models;
import "protobuf-net/bcl.proto"; // schema for protobuf-net's handling of core .NET types

message AssemblyComponentDetailsModel {
   optional .bcl.Guid ID = 1 [default = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000];
   optional string AssemblyName = 2;
   optional string ReferenceNumber = 3;
   optional .bcl.Guid TypeID = 4 [default = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000];
   optional .bcl.Guid CategoryID = 5 [default = 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000];
   optional string Symbol = 6;
   repeated ComponentDetailsModel ComponentDetails = 7;
   optional .bcl.Decimal MsrpTotal = 8 [default = 0];
}
```

The frontend of the project is using Angular 7 and I am using the information on this page to implement it: https://medium.com/francesco-pongetti/using-protocol-buffers-in-a-node-js-angular-web-application-fba17df8ab51.

My question is, the proto file has the import statement `import "protobuf-net/bcl.proto"` and items from this file (e.g. `optional .bcl.Guid`) are being used.  Is this going to cause issue deserializing in Angular?  If so, what is the easiest way to go about fixing this?  There are **a lot** of classes in the project and I am trying to avoid having to try and write all the .proto files by hand.

Any guidance/suggestions are greatly appreciated as this is the first time I'm working with protobuf on a real project.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In theory it *should* just work fine - [bcl.proto is a perfectly normal .proto schema](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/src/Tools/bcl.proto) - however, the types in bcl.proto essentially describe how I hacked .NET types into protobuf. Where possible, I would recommend avoiding that when possible - for example, `DateTime` and `TimeSpan` in bcl.proto *work* but are incredibly awkward to work with if you're not in .NET, but protobuf-net *also* allows you to use the Google types that were added later: [`Duration`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/duration.proto) and [`Timestamp`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto). The reason protobuf-net doesn't default to these is that Google added them *much later* than protobuf-net's support. To use this option (on the types where it works, which is limited): use:

```cs
[ProtoMember(n, DataFormat = DataFormat.WellKnown)]
```

on the property/field. `GetProto`/`GetSchema` will automatically emit the correct `import` statements to match the schema you're generating.

However, in the case of `Guid` and `decimal`, I'd say the options are less clear. For `Guid`, I'd be tempted to use `string` if possible - the reality is that guids have so many ambiguities in the *binary* representation, that using a simple `string` is the most pragmatic option. And `decimal` is *very* unfriendly to non-.NET platforms: if possible, consider using `double` - or if you need to avoid floating point: either use fixed-point via a manually scaled integer, or again: use a `string`.